# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable py 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to keep my discord bot online on replit. I made a new file called

> keep_alive.py

Below is the code I input

```
import flask
import _thread

app = flask.Flask('Keep Alive')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "I'm alive"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = _thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

I'm not sure what I need to correct.

Comment: Can you also show us the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 44, in <module>

    keep_alive()
  File "/home/runner/Gravity-Bot/keep_alive.py", line 14, in keep_alive
    t = _thread(target=run)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
import _thread
#and
t = _thread(target=run)
```

with

```
from threading import Thread
#and
server = Thread(target=run)
```

The error is because you are trying to call the module itself.

Comment: Thank you so much ❤

Comment: @K.Arie np :) Could you mark this answer as correct?